# Asp.Net MVC long time reload after deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, webdeploy

ASP.NET MVC 5, .Net Framework 4.7.2, IIS 10, Windows Server 2019 (dual core cpu, 6gb mem), deploy by Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2019.

The application itself works quickly, there are no problems with performance. But when I upload a new version to the server, the restart takes a very long time - up to five minutes.

What are the options for diagnosing and solving the problem?

Comment: _"What are the options for diagnosing and solving the problem?"_ - Enable tracing and look at the tracing report.

Comment: @Dai how to do that?

Comment: @AndrewG this might help to set up tracing [Tracing in ASP.NET MVC Razor Views](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/tracing-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/)